# aiogram как ловить исключение Unauthorized в случае бана токена бота, и выполнять определённую функцию (условно ту, которая будет заменять токен)

Tags: python, aiogram, исключения, exception-handler

У меня есть бот на Python, созданный через aiogram, и у меня никак не получается ловить исключение Unauthorized. У меня в одном файле есть список токенов, и мне нужно чтобы при блокировке токена, бот перезапускался с новым токеном. Исключение нужно ловить именно во время работы программы, потому что подразумевается что при старте скрипта все токены будут живые.